# Notifications incorrectly displayed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, notification, notify-osd

I have a problem with my notifications on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. The notifications are just plain text with a colored background, and are also strangely placed in the top left corner. I have no idea on how it changed. After one reboot it was just there.

Here is a picture of the problem in question:

[image: desktop]

As you can see the notification appears over the unified menu. How can I restore the original state of the notification bubble?

Here are the settings in `~/.notify-osd`

```
slot-allocation = fixed
bubble-expire-timeout = 10sec
bubble-vertical-gap = 5px
bubble-horizontal-gap = 5px
bubble-corner-radius = 37,5%
bubble-icon-size = 30px 
bubble-gauge-size = 6px
bubble-width = 240px
bubble-background-color = 131313
bubble-background-opacity = 90%
text-margin-size = 10px
text-title-size = 100%
text-title-weight = bold
text-title-color = ffffff
text-title-opacity = 100%
text-body-size = 90%
text-body-weight = normal
text-body-color = eaeaea
text-body-opacity = 100%
text-shadow-opacity = 100%
```

If I check `org.freedesktop.Notifications.service(/usr/share/dbus-1/servies)` it appears to use the correct one.

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
```

Comment: have you tried rebooting again to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Yes, the problem persist.

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed i3 recently? Apparently the i3 metapackage installs its own notification daemon, `dunst`, which gives you that blue, upper-left-corner notification. I solved the problem thusly:

```
sudo apt-get remove dunst
killall dunst
```